# Solspace's Favorites Module

Tags: solspace

Has anyone used this module to mark a post as read or unread using aJax?  Can you share your code?

I am using favorites to mark the post as a favorite (read) and the opposite if they unmark it.

Comment: Just a reminder that the EE StackExchange is here to help with roadblocks but shouldn't be used as a substitute for digging into docs and code. I suggest closing this question and posting a new one if you have issues with your own coding attempts.

Comment: That is the worst answer I have ever gotten here.  Don't you think I spent HOURS looking through the docs.  MediaGirl you have been around EE for a long time and I know that.  But we are not all developers, why does the EE community think that, it's insane and wrong.  So I am not going to close my question.  Maybe someone will answer it, maybe someone that is super cool and willing to help.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question as posted doesn't indicate this, hence my comment as a moderator of the site. SE is a good place to get code help but not a good place to simply ask for code. Happy to help if you post some code attempts so I can see what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a pretty complete tutorial [here](http://joviawebstudio.com/index_ee.php/blog/using_ajax_with_solspaces_favorites_module_for_expressionengine/).

Comment: Answers which link to external resources are not great, because link rot makes them useless in the long term.

Comment: But in defence, Stephen can't copy the tutorial as it's plagiarism and copyrighted, and if it's a decent tutorial that answers the question, why replicate something similar?  I do appreciate the "links are bad" philosophy, but I doubt the question can be answered any other way without bulking it unnecessarily or giving it pointless preamble?

Comment: And now, as pointed out twice above, the link is dead.

Comment: You can still access the link (although the code is quite dated now) here: https://web.archive.org/web/20121231115436/http://joviawebstudio.com/index_ee.php/blog/using_ajax_with_solspaces_favorites_module_for_expressionengine/